# How about afterwork jogging after drinking a lot of caffee?

Tags: sports, heart

I drink many caffee in a workday to boost my work performance (normally 3-4 cups of middle strong arabica).

After work, I would like to do some jogging (maybe around 5 km) to boost my health.

Isn't it unhealthy? Isn't it even dangerous?

There weren't heart problems in my family in the last 3 generations.